# Existence of a variety with prescribed properties

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In [these notes](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~mmustata/zeta_book.pdf) that give a proof of the Weil conjectures for curves, the author writes on page 17 that given a smooth projective curve $X$ over a finite field $k = \mathbb{F}_q$ for a fixed prime $q$, there exists a variety $J(X)$ over $k$ such that for every field extension $k'$ of $k$, the $k'$-valued points of $J(X)$ are in bijection with the line bundles of degree zero on $X \times_{\text{Spec }k} \text{Spec }k'$. Moreover, the number of line bundles of $X$ of degree zero is equal to $\left|J(X)(k)\right|$, the number of $k$-valued points of $J(X)$.

I'm confused about where $J(X)$ comes from. How does one explicitly construct the variety $J(X)$ with the above prescribed properties?

Comment: I don't know. It's not the Jacobian, is it?

Comment: $J(X)$ is the Jacobian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, $J(X)$ is the [Jacobian variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_variety) of the curve $X$.

It is mentioned in Remark II.6.10.3 of Hartshorne's book and it is covered in detail in the red book of varieties and schemes by Mumford.